# Karate Framework JSON path parsing using regex not working for carriage return

Tags: regex, karate, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I am working on parsing the name and description value on the basis of the API body but it fails to capture using below code ... it is failing in parsing those description values which is having \r\n in the description text.

```
$..source..[?(@.name =~ /(.*global.*)/i || @.description =~ /(.*global.*)/i)]
```

It successfully looking for my search query 'global' and consider below as a matched value
'The information is global and it is embedded in the words'

It fails to capture below because it has \r\n
'global data is nowhere capture.\r\n we should do some other tricks.

Can anyone please help what exact regex should I put which would check 'global' from either Name or Description.

Comment: Replace `.` with `[\s\S]`.

Comment: which . @wiktor
.*global.*  - it is for the global text anywhere in the text
So do you want me to write
$..source..[?(@.name =~ /(.*global.*)[\s\S]/i || @.description =~ /(.*global.*)[\s\S]/i)]

Comment: `/([\s\S]*global[\s\S]*)/i` will match all chars, CRs, LFs, etc.